# Ubuntu 14.04 Daily Image Query

Tags: updates

I am planning to use Ubuntu 14.04 Alpha build on desktop. I would like to know that, If I keep updating Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on daily basis, will my OS will reach 'Stable' state when the final stable OS will be released on April 2014 ?

Apologies for poor English.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, if you install 14.04 and keep updating it, when the final release appears your updated system will be the same than installing from the released stable iso, in theory.

I say "in theory" because you're using an alpha build, and so you're exposed to bugs, including the update system.